# How can you make a multi-dimensional array of functions in R?

Tags: r, data-structures

I have a function in 3 dimensions and I want to make a 2D table of pre-computed linear interpolations for the third variable. Ie, given the values for the first two variables, look up the linear interpolation for the third variable. How can I build a multi-dimensional (in this case 2) data structure that will hold those functions and can be indexed.

For example, Id like to interact with the structure as so:

```
a_func <-function (a, b, c) {...}

for(x in 1:n) {
    for(y in 1:m) {
        some_structure[x][y] <- approxfun(seq(0,q,by=0.01), sapply(seq(0,q,by=0.01), FUN=a_func, a=y, b=x))
    }
}
```

,

```
some_structure[_x][_y](z) #and then index it like this
```

Comment: You'll probably want to give a more concrete example.

Comment: @Frank, How's this?

Comment: This may not be an ideal approach because of R's lazy evaluation. i.e. if you use `n` or `m` at all in the function, the function will use the **current value** or n/m when called regardless of what it was when it was assigned.

Comment: @Señor I'm not sure what you mean, but I updated the example.

Comment: If you're not sure what I mean, then I'd recommend not doing what you're doing.

Comment: @ Señor a_func takes `n` and `m` as inputs. Im pretty sure it uses the values that they should have given the normal behavior of a loop. What are you getting at?

Comment: i meant `x` and `y`, those are the variables actually getting changed. If you use n and m, there's no point to using a loop as those values *never* change

Comment: @Señor Aggh, I see what you mean. I didn't mean to do that. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, but here's where the 'lazy evaluation' kicks in: the values of `x` and `y` will not be stored with the function. Instead, whenever you call the function, R will use the **current** values for x and y, which have obviously changed.

Comment: @Señor I'm confused, `approxfun` returns a single variable function, and its argument in this case is `z`. Are you saying `approxfun` doesn't return the function until later, at which point its arguments have changed?

Comment: It's hard to really answer your question because your code returns an error. `approxfun` has no `FUN = ` argument

Comment: @Señor Well the code is of course incomplete, but I don't see anything wrong with the call to `approxfun`. `FUN =` is an argument of `sapply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most space efficient way to go, but this is how I get around holding weird variables in multiple dimensions:
This will return a list (holding nothing) with the dimensions that you want it to hold

```
  list.arr <- function(dimensions) {
    result <- list()
    length(result) <- prod(dimensions)
    dim(result) <- dimensions
    return(result)
  }
```

to access: `lst <- list.arr(c(4,4))`
`lst[[x,y]] #you need to use double braces`
and you can assigned with: `lst[[x,y]] <- ANY_R_OBJECT`

EDIT:
This is actually just a regular 1-D list with a dimension attribute on it meaning that when you call `lst[[x]]` it will return just the xth variable and not the row.  If you want the row you need to call `lst[[x,]]`

Additionally, you can now name the object with `names(lst)`, `dimnames(lst)`, `col.names(lst)`, `row.names(lst)`.

Comment: this looks good. What do you make this 'lazy evaluation' problem?

Comment: Sorry, I can't very well help you here... I know that R does conduct lazy evaluation, but I have not run into such an issue yet... I would suggest to run some simple code and take a look at the outputs and if it works then continue on your way.  If there are issues, a hacky way around that would be to mapply over a vector of "indeces" that you want to use and then make the body of the for loop the function that takes `i` and `j` as parameters